# Highlight dataframe having NaN (matplotlib) while writing to the PDF file(PdfPages)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pdfpages

I'm trying to perform two things:

1. Highlight 'NaN' values with red color for the dataframe.
2. Add the dataframe to the PDF file.

I'm able to display the `dataframe` successfully in the PDF pages, however `NaN` values are not reflected with the red color inside the PDF.

I have tried following code:

```
    df.style.highlight_null('red') 

    with PdfPages('stale_curve_report.pdf') as pdf:
      fig, ax = plt.subplots()
      ax.axis('off')
      ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, rowLabels=df.index, loc='center',colWidths=[0.12] * 15)
      pdf.savefig(fig)
      plt.close(fig)
```

I have tried few other stuffs using `seaborn` also:

```
sns.heatmap(df.isna(), cmap=['red', 'white', 'white'])
```

I think, I need an option inside the `ax.table` to highlight the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by creating a list of colors for `cellColors` in the ax.table function. To do this, we create a logical dataframe `color = df.isna()` , replace the received `True` and `False` with the colors we need, and convert it to a list. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 3)), columns=("col 1", "col 2", "col 3"))
df.at[1, 'col 2'] = np.NaN
df.at[8, 'col 1'] = np.NaN
df.loc[2:4, ['col 3']] = np.NaN

color = df.isna()
color.replace({True: 'red', False: 'white'}, inplace=True)
list_color = color.values.tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')

the_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', cellColours=list_color)

pp = PdfPages("foo.pdf")
pp.savefig(fig)
pp.close()
```

[image]